# Mediawiki Tweeki bootstrap print style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, phantomjs, wikimedia

I am using Mediawiki with the Tweeki skin.
I would like to customize the Mediawiki:Print.css page so when I print into a PDF thanks to PhantomJS binaries and H2P plugin, the templates of the output PDF is the same as the template on my wiki.
Using bootstrap, I take advantage of CSS styling such as div class alert for example.

So here my double question:
- Is there any possibility to tell wiki to print the content with the same styling when I am not in print mode?
- As I can customize the header request sent by PhantomJS to the wiki in order to generate the PDF, is there a header attribute where I could force for example media <> print ?

Thank you :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's a Mediawiki:Default.css page, try editing that with your styles

Comment: Normally you would not edit Mediawiki's original file. That's what Mediawiki:common.css and Mediawiki:Print.css page are made for. But for example, when I try to edit mediawiki:print.css and create an @import url rule, nothing change. It is as if the css is ignored :/

Comment: I have found that updates can *sometimes* require restart of the mediawiki service and that browsers caching the CSS is definitely an issue with mediawiki

Comment: I will try to dig that way to check if there is a problem.
Else, is there any way to force @import over existing CSS such as !important ?

Answer (score 0):

OK so the solution was to edit directly the bootstrap base CSS and delete every @media print references.